# HTML SELECT - Run script onchange from option to another

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, select

I have the following :

```
<select  id="p1" name="p1">
  <option value="ok">Ok</option>
  <option value="closed">Closed</option>
  <option value="ko">KO</option>
</select>
```

I'm wondering how can i run a script on the page only when the value is changed from 'Ko to Ok'.

Answer (score 3):

You can bind change event to your select. You would need to bind the event when the p1 is added to dom for that you can use [document.ready](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/)

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rajaadil/a76TM/)**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#p1').change(function(){
         alert(this.value);
    });
});
```

**Edit** To compare it with last selection

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rajaadil/6F3KU/2/)**

```
prevVal = "";
$('#p1').change(function(){    
    if(prevVal === "ko" && this.value === "ok")
        alert("from ko to ok");
     prevVal = this.value;
});
```

Comment: thank you Adil,but i want to run the alert only if changed from KO to OK. not on every single change

Answer (score 1):

you have to store previous value and on change check what is the previous value and what is current one like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var previousvalue = "";
    $('#p1').on('change',function(){

        if(previousvalue === "ko" && $(this).val() === "ok")
        {
            alert("KO to OK");
        }

        previousvalue = $(this).val();

    })

})
```

[**DEMO FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Q8KUW/)

Answer (score 1):

you can also put onchange="your_function()" in select element

```
<select onchange="your_function()">
    <option></option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think so this should work for you

```
var prev_val = null;
$('#p1').change(function(){
   if(prev_val == "Ko" && this.value == "Ok"){//do something}
   prev_val = this.value
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Jquery [`.change()`](http://api.jquery.com/change/)

Try this :

```
<select  id="p1" name="p1">
  <option value="ok">Ok</option>
  <option value="closed">Closed</option>
  <option value="ko">KO</option>
</select>
```

Jquery:

```
$('select#p1').change(function(){
  if(this.value == "ok"){
     //-- Your Code IF someone select "OK"
  }
  else if(this.value == "closed"){
    //-- Your Code IF someone select "Closed"
  }
  else if(this.value == "ko"){
    //-- Your Code IF someone select "KO"
  }
});
```

According to OP question (`run a script on the page only when the value is changed from 'Ko to Ok'`):

You can use [`Custom Data Attributes`](http://html5doctor.com/html5-custom-data-attributes/)  for storing the previously selected option value.

Try this:

```
$("select#p1").one('focus', function () {
      $(this).prop('data-previous', $('select#p1').val());
}).change(function(){        
    if($(this).prop('data-previous') == "ko" && $(this).val() == "ok"){
       alert('Change');
    }
    $(this).prop('data-previous', $(this).val());
});
```

[Working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/P8tBr/2/)

Above code - We set data attribute `data-previous` when the select drop-down focused once. and than we bind the `.change()` event with select, so when options changed occurred we can check the previous selected and currently selected value and perform our operation (in the above example i am doing `alert()`).